# source command not loading all variables

Tags: linux, shell, source

I have  file containing 1100 variables. Example,

```
LOGPATH=/some/path
VARIABLE2=someVALUE
```

while running `source /path/to/file.properties`

Only the first set number of variables are being loaded. Is there a environment property that defines how many variables can be loaded.

`getconf ARG_MAX` gives `2097152`

```
++ SERVICE_DATA=/some/path/data
++ AUTO_FETCH_LIMIT=25000

echo $AUTO_FETCH_LIMIT

echo $SERVICE_DATA
    /some/path/data
echo $AUTO_FETCH_LIMIT | wc
      1       0       1
```

Comment: Use `set -x` and examine the output

Comment: set -x shows the line is executed.
`++ LOGDIR=/some/path` but echo $LOGDIR still shows no results. Any variables after a specific line is not loaded. If i toggle the positions, the previously missing values are loaded, but the bottom ones are not.

Comment: What does that specific line show in the `set -x` output?

Comment: @muru updated question

Comment: (a) Check for unbalanced quotes in the sourced file. (b) Take out the first 50 lines (in a copy of the file), and see if it fails at the same **line**, or the same line **number**. (c) Use `declare -p varName` for debug, not `echo`.

Comment: Courtesy of `for j in {0..999999}`, I made and sourced a file of a million declarations like `Name_00787123=Value_00787123`. It took 3m28.289s to source, but they are apparently all in there -- checked first, last, and three random ones. There appears to be no limit. ARG_MAX is a red herring: these are not arguments. Maybe `pastebin` your source file.

Comment: there should be an off-line version of https://www.shellcheck.net that you could run on the command line to sanity-check the sourced script (it might notice e.g. those unbalanced quotes)

Comment: Use `xargs --show-limits`. Use `bash -x /path/to/file.properties` to see where it stops. Use `export LOGDIR=/some/path`. What do you mean by "first set number of variables"? What number?

Comment: It's weird that `SERVICE_DATA=/some/path/data` allegedly caused `echo $SERVICE_DATA` to print `/some/path/data` with *leading spaces*. (1) What exactly is your shell? (2) What is the output of `grep SERVICE_DATA /path/to/file.properties`? (3) Is `/path/to/file.properties` really limited to `var=value` syntax? Doesn't it contain `unset` or `declare`? (4) Is the shell "clean" before sourcing? In this context an "unclean" Bash is e.g. after `foo=bar; declare -n foo`. Then run this: `foo=value; bar=; echo "$foo"`. Note `declare -p foo` does show you the full picture, `echo` does not.

Comment: There is no "variable load limit".  The `source` comand isn't for loading variables; it's for script execution. The contents of the file are executed; if it contains nothing but assignments, then it loads variables.

Comment: Could this somehow be a WIndows/Unix line termination issue?

Comment: If you know the last variable that was set successfully from the file, can you update the question with 2-3 lines preceding and following that variable's set line?